# excel sheet is getting unprotected without password after executing the macro which clears filters in protected sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have written a code to clear filters in a protected worksheet. Basically, it unprotects the sheet shows all data and protects the sheet. But after it executes, the sheet is getting protected without a password and it is giving access to delete and insert rows which I restricted while protecting the sheet. please check below code.

```
'Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+p

On Error Resume Next

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="generation@34"
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
    AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True, _
    AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True,          AllowSorting:= _
    True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are calling the 'Protect' function twice.

The second call does not have a password in the options, therefore leaving it protected with no password.

Unless you are changing the settings of the protection, there is no need to call all of your settings again, the line

```
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="generation@34"
```

should suffice in password protecting your sheet with the previous settings.

Also, the options;

```
AllowDeletingRows:=True
AllowInsertingRows:=True
```

Are both set to true, which allows the user to make the changes you stated you wanted to restrict.

Comment: I have replaced the code 'ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="generation@34"
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="generation@34"' with 'ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="generation@34"' but its still getting protected without a password. Please help

Comment: It is the code below this where you specify all of the options which is the issue.
Because it is a separate line and function, Excel is treating it as such, and therefore you are protecting the sheet, with no other options specified, then protecting it once again with all options specified other than a password.
Either remove the second '.Protect' function entirely, or if you do want to specify the options, merge the 'ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="generation@34"' with the options below.

Comment: please check the the code I have edited in my original question , is this how the code should be ?.. I want sorting and filtering function should be performed when the sheet is protected.

Comment: Before the `DrawingObjects:=True`, but after `ActiveSheet.Protect` you need to insert `Password:="gerenation@34"` which will set a password.
Also, all of the settings are set to true, however you stated that only sorting and filtering should be enabled. Set all of the other settings to `False`.

Comment: Apprecitate it sir, this is working. But I am unable to sort in protect sheet. Is there any line of code we can embed in the macro which allows sorting in protect worksheet. Thank you.

Comment: Is `AllowSorting:=` definitely set to `True`? This should allow you to sort whilst protected.